# Pester: How do I keep my script from running?

Tags: powershell, pester

I am testing a PowerShell script. I'd like to test individual functions without executing the entire script. I am not sure if this is the intended use case or supported, and I am not finding a good answer searching online

#### sut.ps1:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
        Position = 0)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string] $Message
)

function fut([string] $argument) {
    Write-Host $argument
}

function Main() {
    fut($Message)
}

Main
```

#### sut.tests.ps1:

```
$here = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$sut = (Split-Path -Leaf $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -replace '\.Tests\.', '.'
. "$here\$sut" "Message"

Describe "fut" {
    It "does something useful" {
        fut 'beer'
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Message
Describing fut
beer
 [+] does something useful 385ms
Tests completed in 385ms
```

Now I can mock away 'beer', because it runs in the describe block. But I cannot mock away 'message', because the script starts to execute when I dot-source it.

In my case, 'message' is an operation I do not want to execute.

I am on Windows 10 15063.

Comment: You're not building your scripts in a way that is able to be tested.  Furthermore, your functions shouldn't call each other in their definitions..

Comment: Before dot-sourcing your script, try `set-alias main out-null`. It should suppress the call to `main`. After dot-sourcing, you may remove this alias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the comments, the issue is that your script is self-executing, so it's not possible to load it for Pester via dot-sourcing without also executing the functions.

The workaround suggested by Roman to temporarily use [`Set-Alias`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Set-Alias) to set `main` to `Out-Null` would work. Another suggestion would be to separate your functions to a separate file (e.g named `functions.ps1`) and then in your original script you can use dot sourcing to include it, but in your test script just dot source the `functions.ps1` file.

Comment: Thanks. I have some shared code in a psm1 and I guess I will be separating business logic and front end in the future to make it easier to test code.

Answer (score 0):

This will only run the main function if it is not called ny Dot Source, as a pester script would. I am using this instead of splitting functions to another file where it is not needed. Then pester runs without invoking the Main function.

```
if (-not ($MyInvocation.InvocationName -eq "."))
{
    Main
}
```

Comment: This seems very useful but how are you importing this into the Pester file to avoid the entire script running?

Comment: I was able to get this working by using `$MyInvocation.InvocationName -match ".+.ps1"` so that the Main function will only trigger when started by calling a script, rather than importing the script from a different script (or Pester file).

Answer (score 0):

If you, for some reason

- want to keep all functionality in a single script (as opposed to in a module or split into multiple files)
- need the functionality to be executed when the script is dot sourced
- want to test the script's functionality using Pester
- don't mind adding some testability enhancing logic to the script

one approach is to add logic that skips auto-executing the script's functionality when a switch parameter is supplied.

I use something like that to keep my Azure Automation runbooks simple (simplicity is debatable; here "simple" translates to "keeping all functionality in a single script file") and testable:

**SingleScript.Tests.ps1**

```
BeforeAll {
    . $PSScriptRoot/SingleScript.ps1 -InTestContext
}

Describe 'SingleScript' {
    Context 'Invoke-Functionality' {
        It 'invokes script functionality' {
            $result = Invoke-Functionality
            $result | Should -Be 'Something useful'
        }
    }
}
```

In the test file above, within the `BeforeAll` block, auto-execution when dot sourcing is skipped with the switch parameter `InTestContext`.

**SingleScript.ps1**

```
param(
    [switch]
    $InTestContext
)

function Invoke-Functionality {
    'Something useful'
}

if (-not $InTestContext) {
    Invoke-Functionality
}
```

In the script file above, you can see the logic that allows skipping auto-execution.